# Magento 2: Add CSS class for country input in address?

Tags: magento2.3, country-regions, myaccount

In the address section at My account dashboard, there is a field
called Country. I want to change the CSS for that country's input.

Where do I need to add CSS class in order to change it?

```
<div class="field country required">
    <label class="label" for="country"><span><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('country_id') ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <?= $block->getCountryHtmlSelect() ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Any help will be appreciated!**

Comment: you want to add class inside <select/>  ?

Comment: Yes, correct but here we are getting that from block. So, I'm not sure where I have to add the class.

Comment: Okay I'll let you know after some time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not to add a new class in that select box. You can use the below class to change the CSS of the select country box on the account dashboard page.

```
.account .field.country select#country { 
    /* your CSS here */ 
}
```

***Hope it helps!!!***

Comment: Thanks. Its working

Answer (score 1):

Where to place the css style is based on the type of change.

**Reference to the [Documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/cache_for_frontdevs.html)**

Check the theme enabled for your website you want to do these changes.

```
Magento\app\design\frontend\<theme>\*\web\css\blackdemo.css
```

Example:
In my case it is.

```
Magento\app\design\frontend\Solwin\freego\web\css\blackdemo.css
```

add the style you want..

```
.account #country{
// place you styles here
}
```

**Dont forget the cache [Cache documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/cache_for_frontdevs.html)**

**Through CLI:** php magento cache:clean

**Through admin:**

[image]

Don't forget the cache [Cache documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/cache_for_frontdevs.html)